# How to set the table view cell to adjust to label?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview, label

I am using Xcode to make an app. Using auto layout, I have a tableview contained in a container view which is part of a view controller embedded un a navigation controller.

This table view is my content page, so the individual tableview cells leads to another tableview which contains bulk of the information I would like to display.

I added UIlabel which contains a paragraph of words to each tableview cells and set the constraints to the respective tableview cells.

In the storyboard, it looks alright having to be able to see all the paragraphs. I have set the line to be 0, and word wrap.

When I run the programme with lets say 4s simulator, the table view cells do not display the whole paragraph but rather, just indicate "..." at the end of each paragraph.

How do I set the settings such that the tableview cells will adjust itself according to the UIlabel after being word wrapped giving a certain screen sizes of phone?

PS: I am new to SWIFT programming and thanks for taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this?:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

This is required for self-sizing table view cells. Also make sure of the following things:

a) The number of lines of `UILabel` is set to 0

b) The autolayout system in the table view cell is proper -- all the views are pinned on all sides and the autolayout can accurately determine the height of the cell.

c) Also do a `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 75` (or your estimated height) for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

add this two line in viewDidLoad Method and label number of lines 0 and dont give any height.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    //cell.customTexLabel Number 0f lines 0 and dont give height contrains just Leading,Trailing,TOP and Bottom. 
    cell.customTextLable?.text = "Here index starts from 0 which means first element can be accessed using index as 0, second element can be accessed using index as 1 and so on. Let's check following example to create, initialize and access arrays:Here index starts from 0 which means first element can be accessed using index as 0, second element can be accessed using index as 1 and so on. Let's check following example to create, initialize and access arrays:Here index starts from 0 which means first element can be accessed using index as 0, second element can be accessed using index as 1 and so on. Let's check following example to create, initialize and access arrays:"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Daniel you can learn how to create self sizing cell here is the demo tutorial for custom dynamic cell

http://developerclouds.com/2016/03/23/table-view-custom-cell-with-self-sizing/